# Overlay on a flexbox while keeping responsivness

Tags: css

With the below code, I am trying to make an overlay for a "progress bar" with text, I need the flex to make it responsive,

BUT the only way I know to make an overlay is to use things like fixed or absolute position, which breaks the layout, is there a way to keep it responsive and have an overlay with dynamic width (for displaying progress).

```css
.master{
  display: flex;
}
.item{
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style='border:1px solid black;margin: 0 auto;'>
  <div class='master'>
    <span class="item">a</span>
    <span class="item">b</span>
    <span class="item">c</span>
  </div>
  <div id='overlay' style='background-color:red;opacity:0.7;width:100%;height:100%;'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would absolute position break the layout?...assuming you have set the positioning context on the parent? - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/OJJZwJW

Comment: You're trying to keep the text centered while remaining responsive, correct?

Comment: make it answer linking the pen and I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute position will not break the layout...assuming you have set the positioning context on the parent?

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.master {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="master">
    <span class="item">a</span>
    <span class="item">b</span>
    <span class="item">c</span>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```